# Two inputs, generate link

Tags: input, hyperlink, field, generator

Trying to generate link from two input fields, title and link text. It should be generated as you type. Here is what I got so far:

```
<input type="text" id="title" value="" placeholder="Paste title"/><br>
<input type="text" id="link" value="" placeholder="Paste link"/>    
<br>
<br>

Title: <span id="text_1"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#title").keyup(function() {
  $("#text_1").text($("#title").val());
})
</script>
<br>
<br>

Link <span id="text_1_link"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#link").keyup(function() {
  $("#text_1_link").text($("#link").val());
})
</script>
<br>
<br>

Combined here:
```

Comment: Found this http://jsfiddle.net/gPsqd/1/ but still need help to make it live - onkeyup instead of click

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: No, the current code is fine. I am just missing the code that will combine these two inputs into link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're lloking somthing like following:

```js
$("#link").keyup(function() {
  $("#text_1_link").text($("#link").val());
  $(".link").attr('href',$("#link").val());
  
})
$("#title").keyup(function() {
  $("#text_1").text($("#title").val());
  $(".link").text($("#title").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="title" value="" placeholder="Paste title"/><br>
<input type="text" id="link" value="" placeholder="Paste link"/>    
<br>
<br>

Title: <span id="text_1"></span>
<br>
<br>

Link <span id="text_1_link"></span>
<br>
<br>

Combined here: <a href="#" class="link"></a>
```